# php laravel creating model instance for a table several times

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, modal-dialog, instance

There is a concept named new model instance in laravel.
But in some cases the model instances are created several times for a particular table.
I’d like to know why there is need for different instances for a single table?

Comment: an existing instance will represent a single row of the table, so if you wanted multiple rows it would be multiple instances which individually represent single rows of the table

Comment: if you want insert data into database you can create multi instance. while there are different ways to insert data. for example model::create function